# curl command has ! character results auth failure

Tags: bash, shell, curl, sh

I am getting authentication failure error while using curl command in bash shell which password has ! char.

Below is curl command i am trying.

```
curl -D- -u 'some_user:somename@2019!' -X POST --data @data.txt -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://help.myjira.com/rest/api/2/issue
```

I have also tried escaping ! char using \, as below, but no luck.

```
curl -D- -u 'some_user:somename@2019''\!' -X POST --data @data.txt -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://help.myjira.com/rest/api/2/issue
```

can any one suggest.

Comment: For debugging, replace your long `curl` commandline with `echo '!'`. Note how this prints an `!` character and does not invoke history substitution. Therefore I guess something else is going on.

Comment: thanks @MichaWiedenmann, tried you suggested, seems like this user does not have permissions to create jira. thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with entity code for `! = %21` (and `@ = %40`). So:

```
curl -D- -u 'some_user:somename%402019%21' -X POST --data @data.txt -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://help.myjira.com/rest/api/2/issue
```